# Taskbar in TOP screen overflows over the window(s)

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I like having the Taskbar in the TOP of screen.
In addition, I've unlocked and made it thicker (2-lined, instead of 1 line. ALSO, I have "icon grouping" off, as I dislike it):

[image]

But quite often, when I start some programs (not all) they are opened as their window's top is behind the taskbar (as if taskbar was 1-lined, it was ok). However, they doesn't respect that my taskbar is 2-lined and thus, the taskbar overflows the top part of such windows.
See the left part of screenshot:

[image]

To align the program's window  well (see right part of screenshot), I have to do one of the two choices:

A) Resize the taskbar to 1-line and then resize back to 2-line

B) Click once on any [side of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGlZ3.png) to trigger the "resize" action (or whatever it's called)

What can be remedy to avoid the above steps and force apps to start with proportion my current taskbar? *(btw, the app in question  is [TextCrawler](https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/tcdownloads.html) that has the problem always, with **WINDOWS 10**)*

Comment: One known fix is to start Task Manager, Processes tab, scroll down and click Windows Explorer, then click Restart.

Comment: If this issue is for one know program only (here TextCrawler) it may be a bug for that specific program.